# ¿Cómo acceder a los objetos privados en la script de un componente?

Tags: javascript, polymer

En [ésta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24442200/1436359) hablan acerca de como evitar exponer objetos privados en un componente. Yo he estado buscando como hacer lo opuesto. Digamos que se tiene el componente especificado en las lineas de abajo y queremos acceder a `privateObj` ya sea desde la página web o desde un componente padre. ¿Cómo se podría realizar esto en JavaScript usando la API de Polymer?

```
<polymer-element name="animating-element">
   <script>    
     var privateObj = {};

     privateObj.internalState = 0; 

     //private static method
     privateObject.setupState = function(polymerObject) {
        if(polymerObject.stateExposedToOutside == /* some conditions */) { 
           privateObject.internalState = 1;
        }
     }

     Polymer('animating-element', {
        stateExposedToOutside: 0,
        ready: function() {

          privateObj.setupState(this);
          this.animate();

        },
        animate: function() {

        }
      });    
   </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Para acceder a un objeto que es privado es definiendolo como no privado =)

Comment: @Elenasys Si, el problema es que es un componente de un tercero, así que me gustaría modificar el funcionamiento de unos métodos que no están expuestos, por lo menos hasta que el autor acepte las modificaciones que realice, y empaquete la nueva version de la aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

Y si solo agregas esto:

```
this.privateObject = privateObject;
```

En teoria podrías hacer esto

```
> document.querySelector('animating-element').privateObject.setupState(this);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Enrique, recuerda usar el botón de código `{}` para dar el formato adecuado.